# Building HTML and appending using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm stuck with a scenario such as the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var param1 = "A";
        var param2 = "B";
        var param3 = "C";
        $("ul#SomeUL").append('<li><%: Ajax.ActionLink("Click Me", "SomeAction",  new { param1 = "' + param1 + '", param2 = "' + param2 + '", param3 = "' + param3 + '" }, new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "onSuccess" }, new { Class = "ABC" } ) %></li>');
```

Now the problem is that instead of the value of each of the param# variables being "inserted"...the variable name itself (e.g. param1) gets "inserted"...in other words the routeValues being posted to the controller action are param1, param2, and param3 instead of A, B, and C...does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Thanks D

Answer (score 1):

ActionLinks are useless in this case as they are server side code. You cannot mix them with client side javascript variables. Here's how I would do it (embracing the full power of jQuery):

```
$(function () {
    var param1 = 'A';
    var param2 = 'B';
    var param3 = 'C';
    $('ul#SomeUL').append(
        $('<li/>', {
            html: $('<a/>', {
                href: '<%= Url.Action("SomeAction") %>',
                text: 'Click Me',
                class: 'abc',
                click: function() {
                    var params = { 
                        param1: param1, 
                        param2: param2, 
                        param3: param3 
                    };
                    $.get(this.href, params, function(result) {
                        onSuccess();
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            })
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: Ok...but will the above code work also if the link is an image that has to be clicked? (I wrote an extension method called ImageActionLink, but just used ActionLink in my scenario above for simplicity's sake.

Comment: @Dieter, you could use a CSS class to apply some background image to the anchor tag. Or instead of an anchor simply generate an `<img/>` tag. You could use a HTML5 `data-*` attribute on this image tag in order to store the url with the `Url.Action` helper.

Comment: But why are ActionLinks useless if I build them up as a string? Why would the strange behavior regarding the javascript variables happen while constructing a string? I checked and even when first assigning the constructed html to a variable first and then passing the variable to the append function, the string variable has the parameter variables' names inserted into it instead of the parameter variables' values?

Comment: E.g. if I say:

var html = '<li><%: Ajax.ActionLink("Click Me", "SomeAction",  new { param1 = "' + param1 + '", param2 = "' + param2 + '", param3 = "' + param3 + '" }, new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "onSuccess" }, new { Class = "ABC" } ) %></li>';

"param1" is in the string instead of "A"

Comment: I just (quite painfully) wrote a function that produces the same html as ActionLink and it works 100%...but I would prefer to use ActionLink as is...any idea why the html construction by concatenating strings doesn't work?

Comment: @Dieter, it doesn't work because an ActionLink is a server side helper. This means that it executes on the server and produces HTML passed to the client. You are trying to concatenate it with some javascript variables. Javascript executes on the client. By the time those variables are instantiated on the client the server has long gone and finished with the ActionLink.